# Condition for guarantee f and f' relative primes over a polynomial ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

PROBLEM:

Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ with F filed. Suppose there is a root $c$ of f(x) of multiplicity greater than 1 over some extension filed $K$. Prove that $f(x) $ and $f'(x) $ are not relative primes on $F[x] $.

MY ATTEMPT:

Because $c$ is a root, then $f(x) =(x-c)^{2}h(x) $ for some $h(x) \in K[x] $.

On the other hand, it's easy to look that $f'(x) =(x-c) g(x) $ through Leibniz's formula, where $g(x) \in K[x] $

With the above, we can guarantee $gcd(f, f') \neq 1$ on $K[x] $. However, I don't get to prove this property to $F[x] $... Can somebody help me with this?...

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $c$ as an element of $K$ over $F$ (which would exist by virtue of $c$ being a root of $f$) would probably be the polynomial in $F[x]$ that is expected to divide both $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Teresa, I liked a lot your Comment, I had not consider that, but, I have problems yet with resolve this exercise. If I consider that the minimal polynomial of c as an element of K over F, let's say p(x), then evidently p(x) divides to f(x), but I don't get to look why p divides f'. I thought to use the multiplicity and prove p(x)^2 divides f(x) and this manner I Could prove easily that p(x) divides f', but I don't either get prove of p(x) ^2|f(x)... Could you help me a little more? Thanks!

Comment: You have $f'(c)=0$. Now write $f'(x)=q(x)p(x)+r(x)$ with $r(x)\equiv 0$ or $\deg r(x)<\deg p(x)$. What goes wrong if $r(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: off course!!! you've helpen me a lot!...thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, good to know this was sorted in the end.